# Are StringBuilder strings immutable?

Tags: c#, .net, string

StringBuilder has a reputation as being a faster string manipulation tool than simply concatenating strings.  Whether or not that's true, I'm left wondering about the results of StringBuilder operations and the strings they produce.

A quick jaunt into Reflector shows that StringBuilder.ToString() doesn't always return a copy, sometimes it seems to return an instance of the internal string.  It also seems to use some internal functions to manipulate the internal strings.

So what do I get if I do this?

```
string s = "Yo Ho Ho";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
string newString = sb.ToString();
sb.Append(" and a bottle of rum.");
string newNewString = sb.ToString();
```

Are newString and newNewString different string instances or the same?  I've tried to figure this out via reflector, and I'm just not quite understanding everything.

How about this code?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Foo\n");
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
string s = sr.ReadLine();
sb.Append("Bar\n");
s = sr.ReadLine();
```

Will the last statement return null or "Bar"?  And if it returns one or ther other, is this defined or undefined behavior?  In other words, can I rely on it?

The documentation is remarkably terse on this subject, and I'm reluctant to rely on observed behavior over specification.

Comment: Please note that the implementation of the StringBuilder has changed since this question was asked and answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Outside of mscorlib, any instance of a System.String is immutable, period.

StringBuilder does some interesting manipulation of Strings internally but at the end of the day it won't return a string to you and then subsequently mutate it in a way that is visible to your code.

As to whether subsequent calls to StringBuilder.ToString() returns the same instance of a String or a different String with the same value, that is implementation dependent and you should not rely on this behavior.

Comment: Yes, experimentation has shown this to be true, but spelunking in the internals with Reflector didn't show an obvious reason why.  It appears to return a reference to the internal string on each call, thus my confusion as to whether the string could mutate.

Comment: @Mystere, The implementation of StringBuilder is a bit daunting at first.  Until I read your question and started exploring I didn't realize they did thread level caching. I plan on taking a longer look later tonight (or tomorrow).  But you can trust in the resulting String being immutable

Comment: @JaredPar - While this is true 99.999% of the time, you *CAN* have a mutable string outside of `mscorlib`... as long as the string is interned.   Gist: https://gist.github.com/binarycow/304d7e23f0b1f55169e1069c829676c4

Answer (score 4):

`newString` and `newNewString` are different string instances.

Although `ToString()` returns the current string, it clears its current thread variable. That means next time you append, it will take a copy of the current string before appending.

I'm not *entirely* sure what you're getting at in your second question, but `s` will be null: if the final characters in a file are the line termination character(s) for the previous line, the line is *not* deemed to have an empty line between those characters and the end of the file. The string which has been read previously makes no difference to this.

Comment: Ahh.. you explained the mystery to me.  Clearing the thread variable is what causes the copy on append, how simple but non-obvious.  My second question was a variation on the mutability question, relating to a reference stored in the StringReader.

Answer (score 3):

> Are `newString` and `newNewString`
>   different `string` instances or the
>   same? I've tried to figure this out
>   via reflector, and I'm just not quite
>   understanding everything.

They are different `string` instances: `newString` is "`Yo Ho Ho`" and `newNewString` is "`Yo Ho Ho and a bottle of rum.`". `strings` are immutable, and when you call `StringBuilder.ToString()` the method returns an immutable `string` that represents the *current* state.

> Will the last statement return `null` or
>   "`Bar`"? And if it returns one or ther
>   other, is this defined or undefined
>   behavior? In other words, can I rely
>   on it?

It will return `null`. The `StringReader` is working on the immutable `string` you passed to it at the constructor, so it is not affected by whatever you do to the `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

The whole purpose of this class is to make string mutable, so it actually is. I believe (but not sure) it'll return the same string that goes into it only if nothing else had been done with this object. So after

```
String s_old = "Foo";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s_old);
String s_new = sb.ToString();
```

s_old would be the same as s_new but it won't be in any other case.

I should note, that for Java compiler automatically convert multiple string additions into operations with StringBuilder (or StringBuffer which is similar but even faster) class and I would be really surprised in .NET compiler doesn't do this conversion also.

Comment: The C# compiler doesn't use StringBuilder for string concatenations - it uses String.Concat. That means the final length is known before any concatenation is performed.